# Gradient Shadow all around View

Tags: android, layout, shadow

I need to set the following gradient around an EditText.

[image: app_bar]

I tried using elevation but I'm not quite getting the effect I need, since I need the shadow to be a very light gradient and to be all around the view, not only on the bottom.

This is my current `background.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="2dp"
            android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and my `activity.xml`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView  android:layout_width="320dp"
                                        android:layout_height="40dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                                        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText android:layout_width="320dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                  android:hint="@string/email_hint" android:paddingStart="16dp" android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                  android:textSize="16sp" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                  android:background="@drawable/background" android:drawableStart="@drawable/search"
                  android:drawablePadding="16dp" android:textColorHint="#8A8A8A"
                  android:id="@+id/search_edittext"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I tried putting it in a cardview to play a bit with the elevation, it didn't work out for the reasons I wrote above.

Would you help me figure out how to have this shadow?

Comment: use [nine patch drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this tool](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) and make a custom background shape for your edit text.
Therefore you have something like this that can be set as a background for your view.

[image]
But it's not really gradient. For that, you should make a nine-patch image, like [this one](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example). So you have that image as a background.